# Was the Prism book updated for Prism 6?

Tags: wpf, prism

The "Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism" (Prism MSDN documentation) is available as a [ePub](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/6/52627B2B-AE05-4781-AA5D-7EBCC4C86D9B/Prism5forWPF.epub) [Mobi](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/6/52627B2B-AE05-4781-AA5D-7EBCC4C86D9B/Prism5forWPF.mobi) and [Pdf](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/6/52627B2B-AE05-4781-AA5D-7EBCC4C86D9B/Prism5forWPF.pdf) for Prism 5. Was this book updated for Prism 6?

Answer (score 3):

This book was not updated for Prism 6.

The Prism Library is now open source, with a new home at GitHub:

- [Prism Library (GitHub.io)](http://prismlibrary.github.io/)

Therefore the updated documentation is available there too:

- [Prism Library Documentation (GitHub.io)](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/)

That includes samples for WPF, WUP and Xamarin Forms.